# How can i print Unmarshalled data in golang?

Tags: json, go, glide-golang

I am reading json from Raabbitmq in golang and mapping the json in an interface

My struct looks like this, and

```
type Documents struct {
    user_id    string
    partner_id []string
    last_login int
}
```

and I am mapping the incoming json in the above struct, but for debugginf purpose, i want to see the interface array , how can i print the mapped data array (body in my case )

```
        var body []Documents
        json.Unmarshal(d.Body, &body)

        log.Printf("Received a message: %s", body)
```

Do i need to put other identifier instead of %s ?

Comment: "the interface array" --- what's that?

Comment: sorry for mixing stuff but i wanted to print the interface so see the data and whatever arrays the interface encapsulates, to check if data mapped correctly,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have problem with your struct definition. You need use Exported identifier, like-

```
type Documents struct {
    UserID    string    `json:"user_id"`
    PartnerID []string  `json:"partner_id"`
    LastLogin int       `json:"last_login"`
}
```

---

For your question, refer to format [printing verbs](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#pkg-overview).

To print values of body-

```
log.Printf("Received a message: %v", body)
```

To print values along with variable name -

```
log.Printf("Received a message: %#v", body)
```